# Reference invalid on update, so, how to update?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

On my dream the `UPDATE` clause (for a table `hh` of schema `s`) was something as:

```
UPDATE s.hh
SET x = t.a, y=t.b
FROM func_ret_table('n',hh.ids) t(a, b)
WHERE hh.z IS NOT NULL
```

but for PostgreSQL is an invalid reference... So, how to UPDATE without redo all software?

The function `func_ret_table()` returns only one row — so not need a "join" in the WHERE clause.

---

**THE ORIGINAL ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "li_raw_compact"
LINE 3: FROM wdosm.get_member_wds('n',li_raw_compact.n_ref_ids) t(os...
                                       ^
TIP:  There is an entry for table "li_raw_compact", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

**Translating** to the above example:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "hh"
LINE 3: FROM func_ret_table('n',hh.ids) t(os...
                                  ^
TIP:  There is an entry for table "hh", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

---

### Not elegant neither considered a solution

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ab_update AS 
  SELECT w.id, t.a, t.b 
  FROM s.hh, LATERAL func_ret_table('n',hh.ids) t(a, b) 
  WHERE hh.z IS NOT NULL
;
UPDATE s.hh
SET x = t.a, y=t.b
FROM vw_ab_update t
WHERE hh.id=t.id
;
```

in my real case I need a complex sql-view... I am using, but is so ugly as solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **exact** error message you get

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I edited.

Comment: The error message does not match the SQL you have shown but apparently the issue is, that you can't use a `lateral` join in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I edited, now with a "Translating to the above example"

Comment: The simple workaround could be: `update s.hh set (x, y) = (select a, b from func_ret_table('n',hh.ids)) where hh.z is not null;` But obviously it is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Why is not valid? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=793e4fa5b555ff12fe32f6b290a8bf2f

Comment: @Abelisto sorry, was **perfect**, is the solution! I stopped trying syntax alternatives, and  `set (x,y)=(select f(x))` is very elegant for this case... You can answer with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to update several columns in single assignment using ROW-like syntax:

```
update t set
  (x, y) = (1, 2)
```

or

```
update t set
  (x, y) = (select 1, 2)
```

etc, see [definition of the `UPDATE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

> ```
> [ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
> UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
>     SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
>           ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
>           ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
>         } [, ...]
>     [ FROM from_list ]
>     [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
>     [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
> ```

So your query could be rewritten as:

```
UPDATE s.hh
SET (x, y) = (SELECT a, b FROM func_ret_table('n',hh.ids) t(a, b))
WHERE hh.z IS NOT NULL
```

---

NOTE: the `( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )` syntax was introduced *only in ~2016* with  PostgreSQL **v9.5**... It is not so well known yet,  but is it is so useful!